# Redirect Ligthbox to another url

Tags: java, css, jquery-ui, lightbox2

How can I make CSS Lightbox redirect to another url when a user clicks the surface of Lightbox popup?

Comment: The SO FAQ ( http://stackoverflow.com/faq) can help to ask a question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onclick event handler `onclick="location.href='http://example.com';"`